# Loading basic HTML in Node.js inside string "html"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I'm thinking if there is any way to load HTML inside node.js as a

string in app.get("/html") Like "<-html->blabla"... 
A normal but inside the node.js code
Cuz I want to put database values inside it not static is there any way to do that? or at least do what I'm looking for

Comment: You could store it in a variable?

Comment: Yes exactly and then load it inside the page when call the url
As lets say i have route app.get and then when i load the html I want something like
"html code"+Count Of Something From DataBase variable+"html Code"

Comment: Which will make it not static anymore

Comment: Sounds like you either want a template engine, or a DOM implementation.

Comment: Btw this is the first time i load html inside node.js I have no idea what it could be i know it could from a file but i want inside the node.js

Comment: Here are the docs if you want to do it properly: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a formatted string with `express.js`, you can do:

```
app.get("/html", async (req, res) => {
    const msg = await getMsgFromDB(); // An example of how you fetch data from DB
    res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>${msg}</html>`);
});
```

Comment: I have a question can i use <script> with this?

Comment: Bro, you forgot the closing ); at last line thank you btw so much!
If anyone never used node.js just put at last line ); <3

Comment: @Nah nice catch, I fixed it